# How to get Icons on button

Tags: html, font-awesome

So I have

```
<a type="button" class="btn mt-2 btn-dark" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzbk3N8EvWBRUKA7Kcdp5zg" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>  YouTube</a>
```

^ Button Works Great. Output: [https://cdn.apilol.pics/‍​⁠‍‍‍​‌​​​‍​‍⁠​⁠⁠‍​⁠‌‍‍​‌‍‌⁠⁠ඞඞඞඞඞ](https://cdn.apilol.pics/%E2%80%8D%E2%80%8B%E2%81%A0%E2%80%8D%E2%80%8D%E2%80%8D%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8D%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8D%E2%81%A0%E2%80%8B%E2%81%A0%E2%81%A0%E2%80%8D%E2%80%8B%E2%81%A0%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8D%E2%80%8D%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8D%E2%80%8C%E2%81%A0%E2%81%A0%E0%B6%9E%E0%B6%9E%E0%B6%9E%E0%B6%9E%E0%B6%9E)

And I have this button:

```
<a type="button" class="btn mt-2 btn-dark" href="http://ez.apilol.xyz" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-"></i>  E-Z.bio</a>
```

I can't figure out how to get the icon like the youtube one has. All I know is the thing showing the icon is:

```
<i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>  YouTube</a>
```

Please help!

Comment: have you added cdn in your html

Comment: `<i class="fab fa-"></i>` you don't have any icon defined, just the prefix for one https://fontawesome.com/v6/search

Comment: Seems like you are using FontAwesome icons (based of `fab fa-*` classes. Check [its icons list](https://fontawesome.com/search)

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href=“yoursite.com“><img scr=“yousource.png“></a>
```

or

```
<img scr=“yousource.png“ onclick=“open()“>

<script>
function open(){
 window.open(“yoursite.com“)
}
</script>
```

Comment: This code doesn't work as you've submitted. Please test code before submitting here.